# "Со временем обречен на провал" ― правильно ли?

Tags: грамотная-речь, причастия, наречия, времена

**Со временем этот бизнес обречен на провал.**

Правильно ли здесь употреблено причастие прошедшего времени **обречен**?
Ведь **со временем** означает *по прошествии какого-то времени, в будущем.*

Следовательно, надо бы написать:
Со временем этот бизнес будет обречен на провал.
Или:
Этот бизнес обречен на провал. (То есть со временем он провалится.)

Answer (score 3):

Видимо, Вы правы, если есть обстоятельство "со временем", всё-таки должно быть будущее время:*Со временем этот бизнес будет обречен на провал.* То есть пока ещё не обречён,только первые предзнаменования,  а со временем этого не избегнет.

Или: *Этот бизнес обречен на провал.* Тогда смысл чуть изменится: уже понятно,что обречён.

Answer (score 3):

Безупречен только последний вариант:

> Этот бизнес **обречён** на провал.

Понятие "обречён" выражает свойства бизнеса в *настоящем* времени: у него **имеются** внутренние причины, будущие **последствия** которых (провал) **неизбежны** (= *"настоящее чревато будущим*").

Поэтому в самом первом варианте *"Со временем этот бизнес обречён на провал."* есть **противоречие** между *настоящим* (ему принадлежит свойство обречённости) и *будущим* (на него ссылаются фразой "со временем") — одно и то же утверждение о *причине* отнесено к разным временам.

Вариант же "*Со временем этот бизнес будет обречён на провал.*" имеет **неясный смысл**: если сейчас бизнес не обречён, это указывает на будущую причину, которая сама по себе не является неизбежной, но если вдруг возникнет, то обречёт на провал бизнес. Чтобы такое предложение было понятным, надо убедительно раскрыть смысл этой гипотетической причины (она важнее прочего — нельзя "гадать" на предмет *обречённости*), а потом уже приписывать бизнесу "будущую обречённость", то есть для этого нужен дополнительный контекст — само предложение малоинформативно, почти загадочно.

Answer (score 1):

Есть семантичeская разница.

"Обречен на провал" — его состояние таково, что он должен провалиться.

"(Со временем) будет обречен на провал" — в будущем произойдет что-то, что обречет его на провал.

"Со временем обречен на провал" (?!) ― не думаю, что допустимо. Если требуется подчернуть, что провал произойдет не сразу, то нужно найти другие слова и изменить порядок слов, например "обречен на провал через некоторое время".